# Column start from bottom left

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to make `Column` start from bottom left? I tried with `Align` but still on top left.

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              destinationImage(),
              contentImage(),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


Widget contentImage() {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultSideMargin),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Rialto Bridge',
            style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 24.0,
              fontWeight: semiBold,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Italy',
            style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 16.0,
              fontWeight: light,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: What I want]

Comment: use`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` in `Column` and remove `Align`

Comment: Can you include your full Widget?

Comment: I've been updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your column widget with positioned widget

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
 const DetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
   body: Stack(
    children: [
      destinationImage(),
      contentImage(),
    ],
   ),
  );
 }

 Widget contentImage() {
  return Positioned(
   left: 0,
   bottom: 0,
   child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        'Rialto Bridge',
        style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
          fontSize: 24.0,
          fontWeight: semiBold,
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        'Italy',
        style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
          fontSize: 24.0,
          fontWeight: semiBold,
       ),
      ),
     ],
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i have updated my ans did it resolved your issue

Comment: Thank you. But, how move to the bottom right or center?

Comment: for right use right: 0 in param of positioned for left left:0 in this way

Comment: [for more detail refer this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-positioned-widget/)